# Is it possible to access Vault on a subpath through an NGINX ingress in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, vault

I would like to access **Vault-UI** through a Kubernetes ingress using NGINX controller. I've tried many things, but the server seems to be doing some redirection.

The simple ingress resources below would not work as the Vault-UI does not know how to handle that specific path and request:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "vault_ui_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "vault-ui-ingress"
  }

  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "nginx"
    rule {
      host = "localhost"
      http {
        path {
          path = "/vault/*"
          backend {
            service {
              name = "vault-ui"
              port {
                number = 8200
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore, I opted for an **ingress rewrite target** ( I know it's not that clean ) like below:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "vault_ui_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "vault-ui-ingress"
    annotations = {
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target" = "/$2"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex"      = "true"
    }
  }

  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "nginx"
    rule {
      host = "localhost"
      http {
        path {
          path = "/vault(/|$)(.*)"
          path_type = "ImplementationSpecific"
          backend {
            service {
              name = "vault-ui"
              port {
                number = 8200
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  wait_for_load_balancer = false
}
```

But even with this the ingress is failing to serve Vault-UI. This I believe is because of the **particularities of the Vault server**. It is important for the integrity of our architecture for everything to be accessed through the Ingress, is it possible to achieve this for Vault-UI ?

The following ingress chart is used:

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  name       = "nginx-ingress"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.type"
    value = "NodePort"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.nodePorts.http"
    value = "31293"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.hostNetwork"
    value = "true"
  }

}
```